# Cannot delete user during the registration when ios APP is killed firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am now currently working on an IOS app. So I want to delete the user account during the registration when app get killed such as crash, or users force to close.

So I create NSNotification (appWillTerminate). As you can see from the code below, whenever app is closed at this page, the notification will get triggered, because I can see my print statement "hello world" in the console. I do not think there are any syntax error or anything. But it just can't delete the user from Authentication.

```
@objc func deleteAccount(notification: NSNotification){
    print("hello world")
    guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID).removeValue(completionBlock: { (error, ref)  in
        if(error != nil){
            print(error)
        }
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser

        user?.delete { error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                // An error happened.
            } else {
                print("delete success")

                do{
                    try Auth.auth().signOut()
                }catch let logoutError{
                    print(logoutError)
                }

            }
        }
    })


}
```

Comment: "But it just can't delete the user from Authentication." What is going wrong? Is there an error message?

Comment: Why are you (trying to) removing the userdata from the database twice?

Comment: Oh sorry I did not mean to delete user from database twice, i was trying to use different way to do it, but i forgot to delete the line. The code above is updated

Comment: Hi Frank, it does not give my any error message. When I kill my app on purpose, I can see the print statement "hello world" in my console. But when I check the firebase, the user info from database got deleted, but not from Authentication. The code never go into "User?.delete" part

Comment: Why is this function marked @objc? It looks like pure Swift code. Also note that *To delete a user, the user must have signed in recently.* which means to delete them they may need to re-authenticate first. You may also want to add a print("test") statement as the first line in the closure to ensure the closure is actually being called.

Comment: I am sorry because i did not show the code in viewDidLoad(), it is a function in #selector